# Remote PowerShell, Local Variables, and ForEach

Tags: windows, powershell

I am looking to get a file inventory  of a specific file on some reomote servers using PowerShell and Invoke-Command. I want to gather the info and then export as CSV to a specific folder.

I have a couple of local variables for the date (to append to the file name) and a list of servers. I understand that I need to use the -ArgumentList parameter to pass the local variables, but the syntax is confounding me with the ForEach aspect involved (I am not a programatically minded person). Here is what I have:

```
$FileServerList = "Server01","Server02","Server03"
$DateTime = Get-Date -Format s

ForEach ($FileServer in $FileServerList) { 
        Invoke-Command -ComputerName $FileServer -ScriptBlock { 
            Get-ChildItem -Path "D:\PathtoFile\*" -Recurse -Include "index.html"  | Select-Object Name,DirectoryName,CreationTime,LastWriteTime`
         | Export-Csv -Path C:\Users\Public\Documents\Data_$DateTime.csv -NoTypeInformation -Verbose 
    } 
}
```

Should I save the script block itself in a variable or go another route? Any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: This question is better suited for [so]. Voting to migrate the question.

Comment: I would be 100% fine with migrating this....

Comment: Are you using `Invoke-Command` for a reason? You don't necessarily need it for `gci` on remote servers.

Answer (score 0):

Since `Invoke-Command` is not called with a separate credential, I assume that the user in current Powershell session has credentials to access servers.

For remote locations, you can use UNC paths:

```
$FileServerList = "Server01","Server02","Server03"
$DateTime = Get-Date -Format s

ForEach ($FileServer in $FileServerList) { 
  Get-ChildItem -Path "\\$FileServer\d$\PathtoFile\*" -Recurse -Include "index.html" |
  Select-Object Name,DirectoryName,CreationTime,LastWriteTime |
  Export-Csv -Path \\$FileServer\c$\Users\Public\Documents\Data_$DateTime.csv -NoTypeInformation -Verbose
}
```